# CSV module sorted output unexpected

Tags: python, sorting, csv

In the code below (for printing salaries in descending order, ordered by profession),

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open('salaries.csv','rb'))
rows = sorted(reader)
a={}
for i in xrange(len(rows)):
    if rows[i].values()[2]=='Plumbers':
        a[rows[i].values()[1]]=rows[i].values()[0]
t = [i for i in sorted(a, key=lambda key:a[key], reverse=True)]
p=a.values()
p.sort()
p.reverse()
for i in xrange(len(a)):
    print t[i]+","+p[i]
```

when i put 'Plumbers' in the conditional statement, the output among the salaries of plumbers comes out to be :

```
Tokyo,400 
Delhi,300 
London,100
```

and when i put 'Lawyers' in the same 'if' condition, output is:

```
Tokyo,800
London,700
Delhi,400
```

content of CSV go like:

```
City,Job,Salary
Delhi,Lawyers,400
Delhi,Plumbers,300
London,Lawyers,700
London,Plumbers,100
Tokyo,Lawyers,800
Tokyo,Plumbers,400
```

and when i remove --> if rows[i].values()[2]=='Plumbers': <-- from the program,
then it was supposed to print all the outputs but it prints only these 3:

```
Tokyo,400 
Delhi,300 
London,100
```

Though output should look something like:

```
Tokyo,800
London,700
Delhi,400
Tokyo,400 
Delhi,300 
London,100
```

Where is the problem exactly?

Comment: sorry, but where's the problem? Both outputs _are_ sorted in descending salary order.

Comment: @isedev ok. firstly, thanks for solving the problem. just another doubt: while compiling the same code on a remote server, i get this error-> global name 'a' is not define <-. but this code works on my computer!

Comment: that sounds improbable... are you sure you have no typos, cut'n'paste errors, same python version, etc... ?

Comment: i am sure i have no typos. syntax errors etc.. might be the python version. but then i wonder what would have changed in python 3 that produced this error? (i used 2.7 and maybe the server contains 3.0 . i don't know..)

Comment: Just tried on Python 3.2. The above code results in quite a few issues but not related to 'a' not being defined :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your code works as described... outputs in descending *salary* order. So works as designed?

In passing, your sorting code seems overly complex. You don't need to split the location/salary pairs into two lists and sort them independently. For example:

```
# Plumbers
>>> a
{'Delhi': '300', 'London': '100', 'Tokyo': '400'}
>>> [item for item in reversed(sorted(a.iteritems(),key=operator.itemgetter(1)))]
[('Tokyo', '400'), ('Delhi', '300'), ('London', '100')]

# Lawyers
>>> a
{'Delhi': '400', 'London': '700', 'Tokyo': '800'}
>>> [item for item in reversed(sorted(a.iteritems(),key=operator.itemgetter(1)))]
[('Tokyo', '800'), ('London', '700'), ('Delhi', '400')]
```

And to answer your last question, when you remove the 'if' statement: you are storing location vs. salary in a dictionary and a dictionary can't have duplicate keys. It will contain the last update for each location, which based on your input csv, is the salary for Plumbers.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, reset all indices to *index - 1* as currently `rows[i].values()[2]` cannot equal `Plumbers` unless the `DictReader` is a 1-based index system.

Secondly, what is unique about the `Tokyo` in the first row of you desired output and the `Tokyo` of the third row?  When you create a dict, using the same value as a key will result in overwriting whatever was previously associated with that key.  You need some kind of unique identifier, such as `Location.Profession` for the key.  You could simply do the following to get a key that will preserve all of your information:

```
key = "".join([rows[i].values()[0], rows[i].values()[1]], sep=",")
```

Comment: Using `.values()[some_integer]` is dangerous because dictionaries aren't ordered: there's no guarantee that you're going to get location at 0, for example.  Second, instead of making a string key, you can use a tuple instead, like `(row['City'], row['Profession'])`.